# VS 2015 shows package loading errors during start up?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I have installed a Windows 10 and VS 2015.
I tried to create a new universal app, but when I tried to compile, it's showing some package loading errors.
Anyone having this issue?

Comment: What is the error in detail?

Comment: More than 1000 errors,i saw that the system namspace missing.